# Wizard like component

Tags: angular12

I am making a registration wizard with five steps in same component. I made two html tables to start the implementation. The first table for first step and so on. I assumed if I make the first table invisible and second one as visible, then the second will be displayed in place of the first. But, the second table is displayed below the first even though the first is invisible. Can anybody suggest how to fix this? Alternatively, is it possible to change the markup of a component in the component's .ts file, like removing the table and adding new, as we do in Javascript using DOM object?

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware of Angular Material UI library. It has Mat-tab component which can be used to implement registration wizard.